# ¿Como puedo bloquear elementos mientras se ejecuta un proceso en una aplicación web?

Tags: c#, html5, visual-studio, web, asp.net-web-api

soy nuevo en programación, tengo un botón que llama a un método que se demora unos segundos en procesar. Mientras dura este proceso quiero deshabilitar todos los elementos de la pantalla (dropdownlist, botones...) para que el usuario no pueda volver a llamar al proceso mientras este se ejecuta. Intente con esto en el evento OnClick:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ddlAnios.Enabled = false;
        ddlMeses.Enabled = false;
        Button1.Enabled = false;
        ejecutarProceso(); // este proceso se demora entre 5 a 10 segundos

        ddlAnios.Enabled = true;
        ddlMeses.Enabled = true;
        Button1.Enabled = true;
    }
```

y estos son los elementos que tengo:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMeses" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnios" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
```

Cuando presiono el botón se ejecuta el proceso, pero no se desactivan los elementos. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Primero debes entender que hay cosas que se ejecutan en el `Cliente` y otras en el `Servidor`. El Cliente envía una petición al Servidor y este responde. Lo que tú haces es en la misma petición desactivar los botones y volver a habilitarlos, es decir `Button1_Click` se ejecuta en todo en una llamada, NO se ejecuta por partes. La solución en ASP.NET depende si estas usando `UpdatePanel` o no???

Comment: No estoy usando UpdatePanel